# How to paste two columns with dash with specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
ID   value1  value2
1     wad     11
2     NA      NA
3     elf     1
```

I want to join value1 and value2 as new column "new" and remove columns value1 and value2 to get this:

```
ID   new
1    wad-11
2    NA
3    elf-1
```

I do it with this:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- ''
df[, new := paste0(value1, value2, sep = "-")][, .(ID, new)]
```

But it gives me this:

```
ID   new
1    wad-11
2    -
3    elf-1
```

As you see value in second row in column new is "-". How to do it right? I need to use only data.table

Answer (score 3):

If you create a new column it will assign `NA` to missing values when you provide conditions that exclude rows.

```
df[!is.na(value1) & !is.na(value2), new := paste(value1, value2, sep = '-')]

> df
   ID value1 value2    new
1:  1    wad     11 wad-11
2:  2   <NA>     NA   <NA>
3:  3    elf      1  elf-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df)
df[is.na(df)] <- ''

df[, new := paste(value1, value2, sep = "-")] %>%
  .[new == '-', new := ''] %>%
  .[, .(ID, new)]

#   ID    new
#1:  1 wad-11
#2:  2       
#3:  3  elf-1
```

I have used pipe operator (`%>%`) just for readability and it is not required part in the answer.